# Why take CMP ECX, ECX?

Tags: assembly, cmp

I am looking through some assembly and I see the line

```
CMP ECX, ECX
```

Which doesn't make sense to me, because isn't it always true A==A? (Reflexive property)

Not sure if this will help, but it is used in this context:

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                         Comments
00414A24  |.  39C9          CMP ECX,ECX
00414A26  |.  F3:A6         REPE CMPS BYTE PTR DS:[ESI],BYTE PTR ES:[EDI]
00414A28  |.  0F92C0        SETB AL
00414A2B  |.  0F97C2        SETA DL
00414A2E  |.  28C2          SUB DL,AL
00414A30  |.  0FBEC2        MOVSX EAX,DL
```

Comment: My only guess was to maybe reset the 0 flag? But I don't exactly see how that helps anything here

Comment: Consider what happens if you omit the `cmp ecx, ecx` and `ecx` happens to be zero.

Comment: ´rep´ and `loop` instructions first decrement `ecx`, and then check the flags.

Comment: Would you be able to give a more full answer as a solution? I would be able to accept it as a solution and better understand the (I can call it a loop right?) Loop. 

The SETA and SETB are a little confusing in their too and could really use all the information you have on this snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ECX register is zero then the `repe cmpsb` is not executed at all.
This means that the following `setb` and `seta` instructions would produce garbage!

Thus the programmer chose to make sure the flags have a defined state.
In this case `cmp ecx,ecx` results in a CarryFlag=0 and a ZeroFlag=1. `setb` will make AL zero and `seta` will make DL zero.

@user35443 `repe cmpsb` does not decrement ECX beforehand. Repeats do check if ECX is zero but otherwise will post-decrement.

@Hans Passant `repe cmpsb` does not need you to initialize the Z-flag nor any other flag except the direction flag.

Answer (score 1):

As @user3144770 says... the `CMP ECX, ECX` clears `CF` and `ZF` (amongst others), because if the count starts zero, the `REPE CMPS ...` does nothing at all -- including **not** affecting flags.

The Intel Programmer's Reference says for REP/REPE/etc:

```
WHILE CountReg ≠ 0
  DO
    Service pending interrupts (if any);
    Execute associated string instruction;
    CountReg ← (CountReg – 1);
    IF CountReg = 0
      THEN exit WHILE loop; FI;
    IF (Repeat prefix is REPZ or REPE) and (ZF = 0)
    or (Repeat prefix is REPNZ or REPNE) and (ZF = 1)
      THEN exit WHILE loop; FI;
  OD;
```

For the avoidance of doubt:

1. the choice of `ECX` in `CMP ECX, ECX` has no significance... `CMP EDX, EDX` would do just as well, and avoid any suggestion that this is worrying about the count!
2. it is **not** necessary to prime the `ZF` flag for `REPE`... so if `ECX != 0` no preparation is required.
3. the flags can be set to anything you like before the `REPE`... whatever they are set to, they are preserved if `ECX == 0` and replaced by whatever the last `CMPS` does, otherwise.

Comment: `cmp` doesn't write to `ecx`, only flags.  edited out some nonsense about truncating `rcx` to 32bit.